# how to delete "NA" bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Good morning

I have a problem with the next graphic, I cannot  delete "NA" bar, in my graphic I need only 1960 $ 1970s. How I can remove this bar in te next code?

```
3a gap%>%
  
  
  filter(region %in% c("Southern Europe", "South America", "Australia and New Zealand", "Western Asia", "Western Africa")) %>% 
  mutate(decade = case_when(between(year,1960,1969)  ~ "1960s",
                            between(year,1970,1979)  ~ "1970s")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = gdp, fill = region)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 3, type = "qual") +
  theme_minimal()
```

Itried to remove "NA" in data frame with the next code

```
gap<- na.omit(gap)
```

but, when I print the cade "NA" bar is on the grapic again

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is currently not [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) since we cannot access your dataset `gap`, but you can provide your data using `dput(gap)` or `dput(head(gap))` if you dataset is large.

Comment: You might be generating NAs when you use `filter` and/or `mutate` -- try using `na.omit` or [`remove_missing`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/remove_missing.html) after `filter` and `mutate`.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely creating `NA` values when using `case_when` - if the year isn't in those decades then R codes it `NA`. You could filter out, for example using similar code for the `gapminder` dataset:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

gapminder %>%
  filter(continent %in% c("Asia", "Africa")) %>% 
  mutate(decade = case_when(between(year,1960,1969)  ~ "1960s",
                            between(year,1970,1979)  ~ "1970s")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(decade)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(decade), y = gdpPercap, fill = continent)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = 3, type = "qual") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

If this doesn't solve the problem for your code then do give a sample of your data so we can figure out if there's another problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was writing is.na in a incorrect position